# How to fill colour part of image view with in border lines in objective-c

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, drawing

Sample image here

[image: Sample Image]

I need to fill only in double lined circle with finger on image view.(Not entire circle at once). And need to calculate percentage of filled circle. 
I tried lot of stuff to draw line. But i am not getting exactly as my requirement. 
Please help me out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uicircularslider) is a sample. You can check the code and upgrade for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to customise existing code what you shared. But its not possible. +1 for quick reply.